# Function becomes undefined when creating dynamic library

Tags: c, linker

A relatively large project is using many objects (mostly from C files) to create several executables and dynamic libraries. For example, one of these files (gxdb.c) creates a function named gxdbkq, which appears (in the details of the object file) as:

```
...
00000000000007b0 T gxdbkq
...
```

However, and when I check the shared library, the function has become undefined:

```
...
                 U gxdbkq
...
```

The problem is probably in the linking phase, but I do not know how to even start troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: Please construct a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, write a small amount of code, show the exact commands used to build it into the lib and finally show the resulting symbols.

Comment: The configuration exec creates a Makefile that is almost 1,000 lines long and a libtool, which is close to 12,000 lines. I don't know how to isolate the problem as many other functions seem to be compiling fine.

Comment: The code can be downloaded from http://cola.gmu.edu/grads/.

Comment: Have you made any attempt? Look at the build log, extract the final build commands and come up with a small code example to try and reproduce the problem in isolation. Its difficult to help with so little info.

Comment: I know that it's a tough one but was hoping that someone had bumped into something similar, and could shed some light. The config log does not provide much info because everything is built successfully from the OS perspective (the problem is that some functions become undefined in the libraries for some reason).

Comment: The point is you have a log there that shows how the problematic lib was built. Try to run those same commands again on a smaller code example to attempt to debug the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is probably in the linking phase

Yes, the most likely problem is that you do not link `gxdb.o` into your library.

Another possibility is that your link line has a "stray" flag which makes the linker ignore the next argument, which happens to be `gxdb.o`.

You should closely examine your link line to make sure that `gxdb.o` is on it, and that no unintended flags are.